# Customize gridview c# windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

My Table has 10 columns fetched from a database, while I need to bind only 4 columns of it to a DataGridView in that 4 column 3 columns from database one of them should add dynamically(This column not in database) extra Windows application c#

```
string sql1 = "Select * From Table";
        SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, connection1);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        connection1.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds1, Reporttype_tbl1);
        connection1.Close();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds1;
        dataGridView2.DataMember = Reporttype_tbl1;
```

Comment: If you only need 3 columns, why are you using `SELECT *`? Use `SELECT {Columns you actually need}`.

Comment: should add one more column.. and fill the data based on two columns calculation need and fill the data

Comment: You could add the calculated column to your query and - as mentioned by Larnu - narrow your query down to the three required columns.

Comment: i am learner.. can u  help me in codining

Answer (score 0):

If you need extra processing beyond the data that you have in your table you could:

(Imagine that you want to calculate the revenue, giving the income and expenses of a business)

1. Use the query itself to do the extra processing for these columns that are not in the database.

For example: `SELECT Name, Income, Expenses, Revenue = Income - Expenses FROM TABLE`

In this case, the Revenue will be calculated as the query runs.

2. Use your C# code to do the extra processing and change your datasource to the new one.

For example:

- Add a Revenue column to your DataTable
- Make the formula for each line
- Use the new DataTable as DataSource

In this case, you are adding the data after the query has been completed, using your C# code to the calculations.

Picking the right one depends on whats kind of work you are wanting to do and what you feel more comfortable.